How to get the right ttyACMx
the command dmesg produce this output when i plug my device on a USB port
> dmesg -wH
[  +9.913990] usb 3-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.091634] usb 3-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1366, idProduct=0105, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  +0.000018] usb 3-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  +0.000008] usb 3-1.2: Product: J-Link
[  +0.000007] usb 3-1.2: Manufacturer: SEGGER
[  +0.000006] usb 3-1.2: SerialNumber: 000683490517
[  +0.027074] cdc_acm 3-1.2:1.0: ttyACM5: USB ACM device


The ttyACM numbers is not always the same (depending witch device connected first etc...)
Is there a way with a script shell  to get the right ttyACM numbers, knowing the SerialNumber by using lsusb or other command ?
Thanks !

Instead of using the /dev/ttyACM* node, you can use the symbolic link created in /dev/serial/by-id, which tends to be unique and unchanging.

Good idea ! Thanks you David
